# References pulled from the wrong bibliography with multibib

Tags: multibib

I have the following problem with multibib: when I use the LaTeX code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,german,american]{article}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{J}{\normalsize{Journal publications}\vspace*{0truemm}}
\newcites{C}{\normalsize{Conference publications}\vspace*{0truemm}}
\newcites{R}{\normalsize{General publications}\vspace*{0truemm}}

\begin{document}

x \citeJ{dokodurime14} \citeC{pikorihl14} 
y \citeR{dokodurime14} \citeR{pikorihl14} 
z \citeJ{dokodurime14} \citeC{pikorihl14}

\bibliographystyleR{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyR{references}

\bibliographystyleJ{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyJ{references}

\bibliographystyleC{IEEEtran}
\bibliographyC{references}
\end{document}
```

then the outcome is:

> x [R1] [R2] y [R1] [R2] z [R1] [R2]

but it should be:

> x [J1] [C1] y [R1] [R2] z [J1] [C1]

Any idea what I did wrong? The three bibliographies are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem relates to initializing the multibib references. I reproduced your problem and found the following solution:

```
\usepackage{multibib} 
\newcites{J,C,R}%
{Journal publications,%
Conference publications,%
General publications}

\begin{document}

etc.
```

Initialized this way, the example gives x [J1] [C1] y [R1] [R2] z [J1] [C1].