# Bibliography with multibib problem

Tags: bibliographies, polyglossia, multibib

For my thesis I'm working with the polyglossia package and now I need to include my bibliography. I'd like to work with multibib, to seperate primary and secondary sources but I can't seem to make it work ; it doesn't include any bibliography. When I don't use multibib and just one of the 3 .bib files, it includes it without any problem.
What do I do wrong?

Here my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{slantsc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguages{english,german,latin,italian,spanish,russian,greek}

\newcommand{\BibTeX}{{\scshape Bib}\kern-.08em\TeX}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{dicosroum,docsroum,roumain}
{
    { Sources lexicographiques},
    { Sources lexicologiques},
    { Études}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{Bibliographie}
\nocitedicosroum{*}
\bibliographystyledicosroum{plain}
\bibliographydicosroum{roumain}

\nocitedocsroum{*}
\bibliographystyledocsroum{plain}
\bibliographydocsroum{docsroum}

\nociteroumain{*}
\bibliographystyleroumain{plain}
\bibliographyroumain{roumain}

\end{document}
```

And here an exemple of my bibliography:

```
@inbook{Asan,
    author = {Asan, Finuţa},
    title = {Derivarea cu sufixe şi prefixe în Psaltirea Hurmuzaki},
    booktitle = {SMFC},
    year = {1959},
    bookauthor = {Academia RPR, Institutul de lingvistica din Bucuresti},
    editor = {Editura Academiei},
    location = {Bucarest},
    volume = {1},
    volumes = {6},
    pages = {203-212}
}

@book{Graur-Agent,
    author = {Graur, Alexandru},
    title = {Nom d'agent et adjectif en roumain},
    year = {1929},
    publisher = {Champion},
    location = {Paris},
}

@mvbook{GLR,
    author = {Meyer-Lübke, Wilhelm},
    title = {Grammaire des Langues Romanes},
    year = {1890-1906},
    volumes = {4},
    publisher = {Fues},
    location = {Leipzig},
}
```

Comment: Are you using `bibtex` on the `aux` files?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean...

Comment: I think the problem might be related to the fact that I can't compile any .bbl of my .bib file. Everytime I push F10, I get the following error message : "Processus en cours : makeglossaries.exe "test2016"

No \@istfilename found in 'test2016.aux'. Did your LaTeX run fail? Did your LaTeX run produce any output? Did you remember to use \makeglossaries?

Processus terminé avec une ou plusieurs erreurs". I don't compile with LaTeX, but with XeLaTeX.

Comment: F10 is to make Index (that one at the end of books). You have to run Bibliography (`bibtex`). I think that it is F11 or F12. You can find it at the Commands menu.

Comment: Right, thank you. Looks like that wasn't the problem. Any of my .bib files as a single bibliography works fine, but as a multibib nothing is showing.

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue?

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, but I think the solution was/is that when you normally use `bibtex` in an environment it compiles the original `filename.aux`. If you then use `mulitbib` and create two additional `bibtex` files:

```
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib} 
\usepackage[resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{App}{Appendix}
\newcites{Fish}{Fishbone}
```

Then it generates `AUX` files, that is `App.aux`and `Fish.aux`, because of the naming in `\newcites`. The issue is you then need to "compile" the bib files. If your IDE or environment does not allow you to do it. You can use the commandline/terminal, by simply navigating to the folder and executing `bibtex Fish.aux`. When you then compile normally to generate your pdf with references, the new references will appear.

**Texmaker**

If you are using TexMaker you can create a command that will compile everything:

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|bibtex Fish|bibtex App|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex|pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

**Issue With Cross References**

If you see cross referencing between the bibliographies and you are not interested in this you can look at [this answer, which solves it for you](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175843/references-pulled-from-the-wrong-bibliography-with-multibib/239492#239492) :)